Mysql query the penultimate matching element from one table to another table
Let's assume that we have two tables.
users_table

id | name
-----------
1  | john
2  | thomas
3  | george


checkout_table

id | cid | date
---------------
1  | 2   | 20240601
2  | 2   | 20240610
3  | 2   | 20240613
4  | 1   | 20240608
5  | 4   | 20240607
6  | 1   | 20240609


I get Thomas penultimate checkout (ID 2) using:
SELECT * 
FROM `checkout_table` AS c 
WHERE c.cid='2' 
ORDER BY c.date DESC 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;

But I can't get this date for each of the users.
I have tried using left join without success:
SELECT u.*,c.cid as userId,c.date 
FROM `users_table` AS u 
LEFT JOIN `checkout_table` AS c ON c.cid=u.id 
GROUP BY c.cid 
ORDER BY u.id; 

Results:
 id name    userId  date    
 1  john    1       2024-06-08 17:52:00
 2  thomas  2       2024-06-01 09:00:00
 3  george  NULL    NULL 

I need to get the penultimate purchases of all users. If the user has no purchases, or has only purchased once, get null.
I expect:
id | name   | userid | date
----------------------------
1  | john   | 1      | 20240608
2  | thomas | 2      | 20240610
3  | george | null   | null

any ideas?
any help will be appreciated,
thank you all

What do you want if there is a tie for last checkout?   For penultimate checkout?  Depending how you want ties handled, you will use row_number or rank or dense_rank, in a subquery

If   there is a tie for last checkout, output any of them.

See example (https://dbfiddle.uk/0MQTIobZ)

Thank you very much @ValNik, it works like a charm, I will study the request
I have a lot to learn, greetings!
